# How to extract Wikipedia list data using DBpedia + dotnetRDF?

Tags: c#, dbpedia, dotnetrdf

I want o get all the list data from a page like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ongoing_armed_conflicts using DBpedia + dotnetRDF.

The wikipedia list page shows a table with all the conflicts and some high level details, but the DBpedia page shows nothing like that, just links to other types of military conflicts:

http://dbpedia.org/page/List_of_ongoing_armed_conflicts

I **don't** want to use sparql at first, but load the tuples (the military conflicts itself) because I need the ability to navigate through a military conflict going deeper and query other types of data dynamically in my application.

Sample code:

```
TripleStore store = new TripleStore();
Graph graph = new Graph();
var nTriplesParser = new NTriplesParser();            
UriLoader.Load(graph, new Uri("http://dbpedia.org/resource/List_of_ongoing_armed_conflicts"), nTriplesParser);
store.Add(graph);
// store.Triples as the conflicts itself?
```

Is this possible?